# Is python lru_chace good for non-recursive functions?

Tags: python, lru

Recently I've heared about `@lru_chace` in python and I tried it out with the following function:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=1024)
def n_words_frequency(document: str, numberOfWords = 1) -> dict:
    """
    This function returns a sorted dict that contatins the frequency of words in document
    """
    words = document.split()
    queue = deque()
    dict = {}
    update_dict = dict.update
    append_right = queue.append
    pop_left = queue.popleft
    for idx, word in enumerate(words):
        # We need to create the queue
        if idx < numberOfWords - 1:
            append_right(word)
        
        # Queue size equals to numOfWords
        else:
            append_right(word)
            expre = ' '.join(queue)
            
            if expre in dict:
                dict[expre] += 1
            
            else:
                update_dict({expre : 1})
            pop_left()

    return {k[::-1] : v for k, v in sorted(dict.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda item: item[1])}
```

The function get a string document and number of wanted words in expression and returns all of the expression with thier frequence.
For example, "my name is liam what is your name" and numberOfWords equal to 1 will return:

```
{'name': 2, 'is': 2, 'my': 1, 'liam': 1, 'what': 1, 'your': 1}
```

Now, when I added `@lru_chace` I got improvment of more than X150 in speed and after reading the `chace_info` I saw that the `@lru_chace` have'nt done anything

```
chace_info -> CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=1, maxsize=1024, currsize=1)
```

Can someone please explain me why was it so helpful?

Comment: Did you add `@lru_cache` to other functions too? I see this code calls some function that is defined elsewhere...

Comment: Hint: `collections.Counter` is much easier to use. And is much shorter.

Comment: @Bakuriu Which function? this code is isolated.. 
The only things I use are `collection.deque` and dict operations

Comment: @wuyudi Thanks, Will use :)